# <ion-slides> or Slides,how can I hide pagination in ionic2

Tags: ionic2, ion-slides

Well,I want to hide pagination.Like below.

```
constructor(public mainService: MainService) {

        mainService.getData().subscribe(datas => {

            if (datas.length >= 2) {
                this.slides.pager = true;
            } else {
                this.slides.pager = false;
            }

            this.handleData(datas);
        });
}
```

I remove `pager` from `<ion-slides>` in html.I want to control pagination's showing status by the code.And when the code `this.slides.pager=true` executed, the pagination still can't show.

Comment: You said your pagination still can't display. So what do you wish to hide?

Comment: when datas.length < 2,I want to hide pagination.But this.slides.pager=false can't work.

Answer (score 1):

// just you can pass the input **`pager`** from template.

```
<ion-slides [pager]="slides?.pager = true"> // OR <ion-slides [pager]="datas?.length >= 2">

  <ion-slide style="background-color: green">
    <h2>Slide 1</h2>
  </ion-slide>

  <ion-slide style="background-color: blue">
    <h2>Slide 2</h2>
  </ion-slide>

</ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem, `<ion-slides pager={{pager}}>`,I contol pager's value true or false in xxx.component.ts file.